# php to import local CSV file to MYSQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I found this bit of code to import a local CSV file on my PC to a MYSQL table. I saved this file as **import.php**.

I found the code on [this](http://www.php-dev-zone.com/2013/05/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-mysql.html) page

```
  <?php

//database connection details
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','test','test');

if (!$connect) {
 die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
}

//your database name
$cid =mysql_select_db('shops',$connect);

// path where your CSV file is located
define('CSV_PATH','C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Images\CSV');

// Name of your CSV file
$csv_file = CSV_PATH . "Booth_shares.csv"; 


if (($handle = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
   fgetcsv($handle);   
   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
          $col[$c] = $data[$c];
        }

 $date = $col[0];
 $filename = $col[1];
 $directory = $col[2];
 $type = $col[3];
 $to = $col[4];

// SQL Query to insert data into DataBase
$query = "INSERT INTO tblshops(date,filename,directory,type,to) VALUES('".$date."','".$filename."','".$directory."','".$type."','".$to."')";
$s     = mysql_query($query, $connect );
 }
    fclose($handle);
}

echo "File data successfully imported to database!!";
mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

When I navigate to **example.com/import.php**, it says **File data successfully imported to database!!** But when I log on to MYSQL, there are no records.

I verify the CSV column names match the MYSQL field names.

Any ideas?

Comment: I found the source code to the game Doom on the Internet.   That doesn't qualify me to ask "It doesn't work, why not?"  questions.  Do you have a specific question that involves some understanding of the code?  Have you done ANY debugging yourself?  Do you understand even a modicum of php, or have you looked at the PHP manual and tried to understand what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in my comment to you still holds true, however, it is highly possible that your problem is here:

```
define('CSV_PATH','C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Images\CSV');
```

Most probably what you actually need is:

```
define('CSV_PATH','C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Images\CSV\');
```